# Is there a way to make a ruby shoes application redistributable?

Tags: ruby, windows-8.1, shoes

The `Shoes packager` doesn't seem to work. I can't make `.exe` files with `Shoes` included, the packager just stops working. I'm using `Windows 8.1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar problem few weeks back. Mostly, packager is broken in its windows version of Red Shoes, but it works perfectly in linux (I have been using Ubuntu). So by any chance you have an access to linux based OS, install shoes in it and then try packaging and making .exe from your code. It would surely work.
Hope it helps :)